# Replace value by group with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset in SQL that looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2
   A     Yes
   A     Yes
   A    NULL
   B    NULL
   B    NULL
   B    NULL
   C    NULL
   C     Yes
```

If the value in Col2 is "Yes" for a specific group such as "A", then replace the NULL values with "No". If the Group does not have a "Yes" present, then keep as NULL.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
Col1    Col2
   A     Yes
   A     Yes
   A      No
   B    NULL
   B    NULL
   B    NULL
   C      No
   C     Yes
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: What if group A starts with both "Yes" and "No"? And are Yes / No / Null the only 3 possible values?

Comment: It will never have "No" only "Yes" or NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work...

```
update table1
set col2 = 'No'
where col2 is null
AND exists (
select *
from table1 a
where table1.col1 = a.col1
AND  col2 = 'Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to pick out the groups with "Yes", then update your table accordingly:

```
;WITH
    YesGroup AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
                    Col1
        FROM        MyTable
        WHERE       Col2 = 'Yes'
    )

UPDATE T
    SET         Col2 = 'No'
    FROM        MyTable     T
    INNER JOIN  YesGroup    YES     ON T.Col1 = YES.Col1
    WHERE       T.Col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to avoid TEMP TABLEs

OVER(PARTITION BY will outperform in BIG dataset I belive

still no reply with MERGE nice task

```
  select Col1,
   Case when tempV > 0 and [Col2] is null  then 'No'
     else [Col2]
     end 

   from (
   SELECT   [Col1]
       ,[Col2],
       SUM(CASE when (  [Col2]='Yes') then 1
       else 0 
      end  ) OVER(PARTITION BY [Col1])   as tempV
   FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_1]
  )A
```

or

```
  SELECT   [Col1]
     ,[Col2],
        Case when   SUM(CASE when (  [Col2]='Yes') then 1
      else 0 
      end  ) OVER(PARTITION BY [Col1])  
    > 0 and [Col2] is null  then 'No'
      else [Col2]
   end  new_value
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea of what you're asking but it's a little open ended (without use of CTE, which is another viable option):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1 INTO #YesGroups FROM dataset WHERE Col2 = 'Yes'

UPDATE A SET Col2 = 'No'
FROM dataset A INNER JOIN #YesGroups ON A.Col1 = B.Col2
WHERE Col2 IS NULL

DROP TABLE #YesGroups
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple :

```
SELECT
    col1,  
    CASE 
        WHEN col1 IN(SELECT col1 FROM @test WHERE col2 = 'Yes') AND col2 IS NULL THEN 'No'
        ELSE col2
    END col2
FROM someTable
```

For an update :

```
UPDATE t
SET 
    col2 = 'No'
FROM someTable t
JOIN someTable t2 ON t.col1 = t2.col1 AND t2.col2 = 'Yes'
WHERE 
    t.col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `EXISTS` :

```
select Col1, coalesce(Col2, 'No') as Col2
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = 'Yes');
```

Now, you can use `UPDATE` statement :

```
update t  
    set Col2 = 'No'
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = 'Yes') and
      Col2 is null;
```